# How do I add pages to an existing AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

I have a pre-built AngularJS application for user authentication using the MEAN Stack. I also have several standalone HTML pages that I would like to include with the app. The purpose of the inclusion would be to include the navigation bar to include user data.

https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/ - This was the app I built off of.

I have tried simply adding a route inside of my app.js like so:

**APP.JS**

```
! function() {
function n(n, e) {
    n.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "home/home.view.html",
        controller: "homeCtrl",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    }).when("/register", {
        templateUrl: "/auth/register/register.view.html",
        controller: "registerCtrl",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    }).when('/video', {
    templateUrl: 'video/video.html',
    }).when("/login", {
        templateUrl: "/auth/login/login.view.html",
        controller: "loginCtrl",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    }).when("/profile", {
        templateUrl: "/profile/profile.view.html",
        controller: "profileCtrl",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    }), e.html5Mode(!0)
}
```

The issue that  I face here is that all of my styling is completely thrown out as well as some javascript that is used in the page is thrown out. Which this page is to use a video player and that isn't displaying as well.

Here is some snippets from **Video.HTML** to show what I'm using:

```
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/clean-blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-comments.css">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery Comments -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-comments.js"></script>
<script src="js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data/comments-data.js"></script>

<!-- Init jquery-comments -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#comments-container').comments({
                profilePictureURL: 'https://viima-app.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_profiles/user-icon.png',
                roundProfilePictures: true,
                textareaRows: 1,
                enableAttachments: true,
                getComments: function(success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(commentsArray);
                    }, 500);
                },
                postComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                putComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                deleteComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success();
                    }, 500);
                },
                upvoteComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                uploadAttachments: function(dataArray, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(dataArray);
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
<navigation></navigation>
<body ng-view>
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image:  v     url('img/johnnycash.jpg')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <span class="subheading">Span text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<video width="1080" height="500" poster="media/cars.png">
    <source src="media/cars.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: false,
        videoVolume: 'horizontal',
        features: ['playpause','progress','volume','fullscreen']
    });
});
</script>
<hr>
<!-- Main Content -->
<div id="comments-container"></div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.instagram.com">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Copyright 2016</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<!--script src="js/jquery.js"></script-->

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm not sure if what i'm trying to do can be done. I even tried building a separate app that uses the same backend to pull the information but I failed at that miserably. Skills aren't up to par on something like that yet.

I have serveral ideas of how to make it work if anyone could find one and run with it or come up with a better one i'd appreciate it 
- build two different AngularJS pages. 
- Build a separate app that talks to the same MongoDB - seems very challenging 
- When I try removing the styling from Index.HTML of the AngularJS application it still does not like mine

Comment: Probably the first thing that I would do is to use the browser's debugger to *look at* the HTML that is being sent in response to the various requests. Look also for errors ("404's," and so on) that are being thrown by the browser after various changes have been made. Also, bear in mind that `when` clauses are evaluated *in order of occurrence,* not "best fit."

Answer (score 3):

Angular treat's `video.html` as a template so it ignores everything except contents of the body tag.

You need to add `<head>` contents and `<script>` tags from `video.html` into your main HTML file (the one in which you have `ng-app` directive).

Comment: I tried this before but it was not working. This time you said "EVERYTHING" so included the inline javascript as well and everything appears to work. Still playing to confirm that it's working. But if this solution causes an issue, I'll be sure to post for others to see.

Comment: But will I have to add a route for every page inside of the standalone HTML? This was just trying to add one this time

Comment: If you want to have navigation of your entire website in angular then yes. You have to add route for every angular view you want to have. It's not exactly a page.

Comment: And honestly i would suggest to have only "content" markup in templates and move styles, scripts and metatags to the main HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the purpose of your web app or any other details, I can try to give my best advice.

Angular JS routes are used for internal navigation only.  Meaning that you can't set up a route that navigates outside the angular app ecosystem (i.e. your video.html page).  I don't see the source code for your navigation, but you could do something like this to navigate to the video.html page and bypass the ngRouter.

```
<a target="_self" href='/video.html'>Videos</a>
```

(More information on that here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting)

As far as the CSS issue, I believe it is caused by the Style tags not being inside a  block.  One thing to do is check the web developer console.  Open Chrome (or your browser of choice) and hit Cmd + alt + i (on mac).  Or go to **View->Developer->Developer Tools** and click on the **console** tab.  You can see any errors or warnings there.